# How to get widgets to admit to what events they can really handle

Tags: go, widget, fyne

I’m struggling with Go and Fyne, being new to both and too used to C++, Python and other OO languages. I’m trying to imbue a number of different kinds of Fyne widgets with certain common behavior, and I’m lost. As an example, I need to create variations on many widgets, like Label and Button, to allow me to catch right click (TapSecondary) so I can do something special (generally, pop up a menu). Yes, I want popup menus on things like Buttons and Labels; I’ll even want to intercept it on Entry boxes (even though I have to implement Paste myself that way.)

I found an example online that offered this to allow me to intercept clicks on Labels:

```
type TapLabel struct {
   *widget.Label //composition

    //function pointers to set to get events
    OnTapped func() //`json:"-"`
    OnTappedSecondary func() //`json:"-"`  (what are these for anyway?)
}

func NewTapLabelWithStyle(text string, alignment fyne.TextAlign, style fyne.TextStyle, 
                          tappedLeft func(), tappedRight func()) *TapLabel {
   return &TapLabel{
      widget.NewLabelWithStyle(text, alignment, style),
      tappedLeft, tappedRight,
   }
}

//somehow this catches right click. How?
func (mc *TapLabel) TappedSecondary(pe *fyne.PointEvent) {
    if mc.OnTappedSecondary != nil {
        mc.OnTappedSecondary()
    }
}

func (mc *TapLabel) Tapped(pe *fyne.PointEvent) {
    if mc.OnTapped != nil {
        mc.OnTapped()
    }
}
```

So, it works. I can call NewTapLabelWithStyle  and pass it functions for tappedLeft and tappedRight, and they get called when I click on the Label.

The problem is that if I hadn’t found that code sample online, I would never have known or been able to work out that Label allows you to define TappedSecondary and  Tapped in a composed struct and catch things that way. I will need to catch those and other events, like runes and keys, on a variety of widgets. Where do I find the function names that widgets quietly support but don’t mention in https://godoc.org/ ? I know this has something to do with interfaces, because the code sample mentioned that nothing would work if you didn’t create definitions for both Tapped and  TappedSecondary even if you only wanted one. Something somewhere has the ability to ask what interfaces are supported by each widgets and acts accordingly, but where is the mechanism defined?

(Go is making me miss C++, where you’d define a Widget class and give it virtual hooks for all possible mouse, key, etc events and then you could override as needed and do things and it was all, by definition, visible. This seems a lot more obscure.)

Edit: So if I'm reading the answer right, Go has some way of querying whether the widget that's receiving input implements various interfaces. Somewhere, there has to be the equivalent of

```
/* pseudocode for handling a right click */
if (thisWidget is Tappable) { 
   ((Tappable)thisWidget).SecondaryTap(pe)
}
```

How does it do that? A verb like "is" makes sense in Python, and C++'s equivalent would be dynamic_cast and a check for nullptr, but how does Go offer that? I'm hoping once I know the syntax I can search the go code base and find what widgets handle what interfaces.

Comment: Having had a very quick look at https://godoc.org/fyne.io/fyne (the package documentation), I'd say the main issue here is that the documentation is just not adequate. As you write Go code you'll get used to the notions behind interface types and not miss virtual functions much, or even at all, but that definitely takes time. It's possible to write obscure code in any language, though.

Comment: A useful trick here: jump to the bottom of the page, where you see `directories`, then click on each one. What makes the documentation not-really-adequate is that you'll pretty much have to read all of them. Hopefully there aren't too many. In this case, for instance, click on `widget` and bring up the widget page where you'll find https://godoc.org/fyne.io/fyne/widget#Label which describes the `widget.Label` type. But there's no clue that a label itself could be Tappable, or not Tappable; Tappable is just an interface (https://godoc.org/fyne.io/fyne#Tappable).

Comment: If (some) Label-ish `struct` types are in fact tappable, that's because those struct types implement the `Tappable` interface, so that's what you're doing here. But I did not find, in my brief look, whether there's some part of the documentation that says "when the user does a button click, the system will search, via algorithm A, for something that implements the Tappable interface". Either that documentation is required, or you'll have to read the code that handles button clicks to find out that this is the case.

Comment: Documentation that calls out which algorithms run on which events (button clicks, mouse movements, etc) is very necessary, and would be if this were a C++ library too.

Comment: In C++ there'd be a class Widget, with a bunch of functions to handle inputs offered as virtual. Subclasses like Label would override the virtual functions, very visibly. You could trivially subclass Label, see what to override, etc.. You don't need even documentation, to see what needs to be done.
Go's a very different language and an interesting one, but that fact that there's no explicit "implements" keyword to show what connections exist is a learning curve nightmare. And it's creepy that just adding a new function to an interface will mysteriously break existing code at run time...

Comment: The (very) rough equivalent of a C++ dynamic cast is Go's interface conversion, as andy.xyz noted, or the similar interface type switch: `switch v := i.(type) { ... }` in which you write a `case` for each expected type, then use the value in `v` that is of that type if that `case`'s code is entered. It's not that adding a new function to an *interface* breaks existing code, it's that adding a new *receiver* to a *concrete* type changes the operations that are do-able on that concrete type.

Comment: For instance, adding `func (T receiver) String() string { ... }`  provides a *Stringer* for type `T`, which `fmt.Println` (the entire fmt family) will call when using `%s` format on that object. So you can get custom formatting for your (concrete) types by making them support the Stringer interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Label does not itself support tapping - you are adding that functionality in the code you added. Any widget that implements Tappable (https://godoc.org/fyne.io/fyne#Tappable ) will fire on tap events. Widgets are free to handle any of the events Fyne understands by implementing similar interfaces.

This is not “hidden functionality” of Label but it certainly could be better documented. It should probably be added to https://tour.fyne.io/

Comment: close to accepting this as the answer, but I edited the question to get a little more understanding. Thanks!

Comment: The mechanics of it are a Go type test, I.e: “if tapObj, ok := obj.(*fyne.Tappable); ok { ... }”